# Best grouping rows method with Multi-Armed Bandit

Tags: artificial-intelligence, multiarmed-bandit

I have a dataframe , here above a sample :

```
cluster   Browser   OS   page   convert
0-3         10      11   100      10
0-3         09      10   100      10
0-3         10      11   101      50
4-7         09      10   101     100
4-7         09      10   100      20
4-7         08      10   100      30
```

the object of this task  is to find the best way of group the records that have the value of 3 columns (3 columns except convert) are same  to maximize the sum of convert .

For example there is a possibility to group these rows (group by cluster   Browser   OS):

```
0-3         10      11   100      10
0-3         10      11   101      50
```

and we got this result

```
 0-3         10      11   100, 101      60
```

Or maybe it is better to group by : cluster, OS and page like this :

```
   4-7         09      10   100      20
   4-7         08      10   100      30
```

to have

```
  4-7         08, 09      10   100      50
```

I am not sure if Multi-Armed Bandit can solve this kind of problem. Can you help me please to have an idea to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to compute the "within group variation". Theoretically, within group variation should be small because subjects (rows) in the same group/cluster are similar. By comparing within group variations (smaller is better), then you can easily to tell how to group/cluster these rows.

Comment: thank you for your response, but here in my task the better groupement is the groupment which have the bigger sum of convert.. I am not sure if "within group variation"  can be the solution

Comment: sum of convert is just a sum of your response variable, it does not tell how similar between subjects. For example, group A has 3 subject: 100, 101, 101.3 and group B also has three subjects: 2, 4, 3. Based on these toy data, you can tell, why we need to compute within group variation.